# Ciclo con variable dependiente de otra variable Python

Tags: python, lista

los pongo en contexto, tengo el siguiente código:

```
opcion = int(input("ingrese mesa: "))
if opcion == 1:
    opcion2 = int(input("ingrese plato (0 para terminar): "))
        while opcion2 != 0:
            carta()
            x = opcion2 - 1
            mesa6.append((nombres[x],precios[x],tipos[x]))
            c6 += 1
            opcion2 = int(input("ingrese plato (0 para terminar): "))
```

Y necesito una función que haga una sumatoria de todos los precios que fueron agregado a la lista *mesa6* que esta dentro del ultimo **while**, la verdad es que no tengo muchas ideas, pero tenia pensado hacer un ciclo **for** que recorriera la lista *mesa6* en un rango de la variable *c6* pero dado a que debo hacerlo de forma general para 6 diferentes lista no se como formularlo.

Entenderán mejor viendo el código completo, ya tuve problemas para los **append** a la lista *mesa[x]* ya que quería que fuera una función que pudiera variar según la variable x pero no supe como así que mi código se volvió un poco grande con tantos **if**:

https://pastebin.com/XrgDFqNH

Comment: Podrías crear el arreglo `mesas`, en donde cada elemento sea un objeto que incluya el número de la mesa y los `platos` que pidieron. Ej: `mesas = [{ nro: 1, platos: [{ nombre: 'Pizza', cant: 1}, {nombre: 'Hamburguesa', cant: 2}] ]`. No es conveniente usar variables en este problema, es mejor usar un arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

si no me equivoco estas iterando una tripla y tienes que sumar los precios eso se podria solucionar de la siguiente manera

```
suma = 0
for i in mesa:
    suma += int(i[1])
```

aqui estas definiendo la suma y luego iteando las triplas para sumar los precios de la mesa, pero para hacer esto en todas las mesas te recomiedo manejar con clases

```
class Mesa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.numero = 0
        self.names = []
        self.prices = []
        self.types = []
        self.names = ["Papas", "Arroz"]
        self.prices = ["200", "2000"]
        self.types = ["tipo 1", "tipo 2"]
    def agregar_info(self):
        option = int(input("Put table: "))
        option2 = 210
        while option2 != 0:
            self.numero = option
            option2 = int(input("Put the id of food (0 to end): "))
            x = option2 - 1
            self.names.append(self.names[x])
            self.prices.append(self.prices[x])
            self.types.append(self.types[x])
        #etc

    def cuenta(self):
        suma = 0
        for i in self.prices:
            suma += int(i)
        return suma


#Hacer la interfaz en consola

#Agregar datos


mesa = Mesa()
mesa.agregar_info()
print(mesa.cuenta())
```

espero haberte ayudado, saludos

Comment: Interesante tu respuesta y muchas gracias por el tiempo y dedicación, el problema al usar las *clases* es que yo tengo que seguir un cierto listado de temas que nos han pasado en clase, y las *clases* como tal no las he visto, es decir no se usarlas por lo tanto dentro del código no podria estar. Graciar por tu tiempo